# Why $(X_0,\dots, X_\tau)$ is measurable w.r.t $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ for stopping time of a discrete time process?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Consider discrete time stochastic process $(X_0,\dots, X_i,\dots)$ adapted to filtration $\mathcal{F}_i$. Let $\tau$ be a stopping time. The following corollary is found in [https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~tkemp/280C/46.1.Strong-Markov-After.pdf](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Etkemp/280C/46.1.Strong-Markov-After.pdf) on page 3.

Cor: $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ (Sigma algebra of stopping time) is independent of process $(X_{\tau+i})_{0\leq i}$ after conditioning upon $\tau$ finiteness and $X_\tau=x$.

Then on the last page of notes, it says $(X_0,\dots, X_\tau)$ is conditionally independent of $(X_\tau,X_{\tau+1},\dots)$ by conditioning upon $\tau$ finiteness and $X_\tau=x$.

$Q:$ Why is $(X_0,\dots, X_\tau)$ is even $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ measurable? $X_\tau$ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ measurable. Since $\sigma(X_0)\subset\mathcal{F}_0\subset\mathcal{F}_n$ for all $n$, it follows that $X_0\in\mathcal{F}_\tau$. Consider $B\in\sigma(X_1)\subset\mathcal{F}_1$. Suppose $B\not\in\mathcal{F}_0$. Then $(\tau=0)\cap B$ may not even inside $\mathcal{F}_0$ by definition of $\mathcal{F}_\tau$. In particular, $X_1$ might not even be $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ measurable.

$Q':$ Why it follows that $(X_0,\dots, X_\tau)$ is conditionally independent of $(X_\tau,X_{\tau+1},\dots)$ by conditioning upon $\tau$ finiteness and $X_\tau=x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\tau$ is random, the r.v. $X_k$ in on the list $(X_0,\ldots,X_\tau)$ only if $\tau\ge k$.

One way to think about what the *informal* notation $(X_0,\ldots,X_\tau)$ means is to think in terms of the events determined by $X_0,\ldots,X_\tau$, restricted to $\{\tau<\infty\}$.
These are the events of the form
$$
\cup_{n=0}^\infty\{(X_0,\ldots,X_n)\in B_n, \tau=n\},\qquad(\dagger)
$$
where $B_n$ is a measurable subset of $S^n$, for each $n$. As $\sigma(X_0,\ldots,X_n)\subset\mathcal F_n$, the event ($\dagger$)  is an element of $\mathcal F_\tau$.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I think I forgot to consider that the case $\sigma(X_1)\in \mathcal{F}_\tau$ I was considering was $1\leq \tau$. That is the part which I was missing.